# Number of games a particular user has played today where there is no data

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the number of games that summoners in the queue have played today. I have tried several queries.  The closest I have gotten is:

```
   SELECT 
        s.summoner,
        s.wins,
        COUNT(*) as playedToday
   FROM summoners s
   LEFT JOIN teams_players tp ON tp.summoner_id = s.summoner
   LEFT JOIN teams t ON t.id = tp.team_id
   LEFT JOIN matches b ON t.id = b.blue_id
   WHERE
        b.played_on = DATE(NOW())
        s.in_queue;
```

But that doesn't give the count per-user.  It just gets the overall count.

None of the tables have any data on any of the summoners.  What I'd like is something like:

```
    +-----------------+------+-------------+
    | summoner        | wins | gamesPlayed |
    +-----------------+------+-------------+
    | DotAliscious    |  353 |           0 |
    | Kraator         |  440 |           0 |
    | Nammon          |  667 |           0 |
    | VictorousSecret |  843 |           0 |
    | Canas           |  544 |           0 |
    | Sprognak        |  502 |           0 |
    | Ghostilocks     |  808 |           0 |
    | b0b d0e         |  224 |           0 |
    | Metroshica      |  339 |           0 |
    | RubenatorX      |  478 |           0 |
    +-----------------+------+-------------+
```

I can't think how to express this problem generically, which is why I haven't found a solution.

---

My data set.  Note that `teams.id` matches up with `matches.blue_id` and `matches.purple_id`.

```
mysql> DESCRIBE summoners;
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| icon         | int(11)     | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| summoner     | varchar(32) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| skype        | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email        | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| in_queue     | tinyint(1)  | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| wins         | int(11)     | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| level        | int(11)     | NO   |     | 1       |                |
| lan_wins     | int(11)     | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| played_today | int(11)     | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DESCRIBE matches;
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| blue_id   | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| purple_id | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| status    | varchar(32) | NO   |     | display             |                |
| played_on | datetime    | NO   |     | 2012-04-06 13:53:55 |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DESCRIBE teams;
+---------+-------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default    | Extra          |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL       | auto_increment |
| outcome | varchar(32) | NO   |     | incomplete |                |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DESCRIBE teams_players;
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| team_id     | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| summoner_id | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `played_on` is `datetime` and you are comparing it with `date` maybe that's your problem. YOu should try:

```
WHERE
    DATE(b.played_on) = DATE(NOW())
```

Also what do you mean by `s.in_queue`? Did you forget the AND? Do you mean

```
 WHERE
    DATE(b.played_on) = DATE(NOW())
    AND
    s.in_queue;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to use a subselect to get the count of records that meet the condition, and that will return you a 0 if the condition is false.  Something along the lines of

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM matches b WHERE b.blue_id = t.id AND b.played_on = DATE(NOW())) AS playedToday
```

and you will want to remove the `LEFT JOIN` to the `matches` table and the `WHERE` clause checking the date.